# Java communicate with Kepware OPC Server

Tags: java, opc, kepserverex

I am looking for a way to communicate java with the Kepware OPC Server. I want Java program to read & write Kepware OPC Server tags. I have searched through out the internet, but I didn't find a way to do this. Is it possible with Java?

Comment: http://www.opcconnect.com/java.php Did you look here? Manufacturer of the server **should** not matter.

Comment: I am totally new to OPC server specially with Java. Could you tell me from where to start, I mean some code examples to connect with Kepware OPC Server.

Comment: The link I gave above should lead you to plenty information about OPC in general and Java Client Libs, particularly.

Comment: I would suggest using OPC UA with KepServer instead of OPC Classic, if possible. http://www.opcconnect.com/uakit.php is the respective link to the tools. Although the opcconnect site is not perfectly up to date, I think this information is still pretty much valid.

Comment: I develop and maintain an open source Java OPC-UA SDK: https://github.com/digitalpetri/opc-ua-sdk